# Getting the current state of a tag

Tags: python-3.x, tkinter

```
config = canvas.itemconfig(line)
```

This will pull off the entire current configuration state of a line on a canvas.

I want to pull off the 'tags' item and examine the current state of it, typically either '0' or 'current'.  How do I do it?  I'm not good at all with tuples/dictionaries and in the research I've been doing over the past hour or so hasn't helped any so I figured stop wasting the time and ask.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You need to use `itemcget` to get the value of a single configuration item.

```
tags = canvas.itemcget(tag_or_id, "tags")
```

Note: if `tag_or_id` refers to more than one item, this will return the configuration value for the first item.

Here's one place where it's documented:

- http://effbot.org/tkinterbook/canvas.htm#Tkinter.Canvas.itemcget-method

Comment: Thanks that did the trick.  Now to see what kind of nightmare programming headache finding this out could end up causing.